# How to list elements of an array in the order of number of their occurrences?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have an array like this.

```
$array = array(
'Element1', 
'Element2', 
'Element3', 
'Element1', 
'Element1', 
'Element4', 
'Element4', 
'Element2', 
'Element2', 
'Element2', 
'Element2', 
'Element4', 
'Element5', 
'Element5' );
```

I want an array like this as output.

```
$output = array('Element2' , 'Element1', 'Element4', 'Element5', 'Element3');
```

So, what i want is:

1. Remove all the elements from the array which repeat.
2. Order the output array in such manner that the element which occured most in the input array is on top.

Comment: IMO: This is not relevant to CakePHP, you should remove that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/array-count-values) and [`sort()`](http://php.net/sort)

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i also get frequencies of all elements?

Comment: That's what array_count_values does - if you click the link you can read the PHP manual on it. It will return an array which you can do a print_r on and see the values.

Comment: Your post doesn't say anything about a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Okay. What if all those elements (Elemen1, Element2..) are themselves an array?

Comment: And you're comparing what about each array? The entire array? One key? Honestly it's a little rude IMO to waste a bunch of people's time by not giving very important information about your question and then making us ask you over and over. Now I'm really glad I DIDN'T write a bunch of code like Corrupt sugggested ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31634/discussion-between-ayush-mishra-and-jessica)

Comment: Everything is same. It was actually a multidimensional array, having many repeating arrays within it. I thought it will work the same if i replace those arrays with elements in the question on stackoverflow. But, I was wrong as an array key can't be an array.

Answer (score 3):

It should be ok:

```
$numbers = array_count_values($array);

arsort($numbers); // Thanks Jessica!
$result = array_keys($numbers);
```

Comment: arsort() - he wants them DESC order.

Comment: @AliTrixx yes, haven't noticed this.

Answer (score 3):

Your expected output is contradictory to your requirements listed. Element5 should come before Element3

```
<pre>
<?php
$values = array(
'Element1', 
'Element2', 
'Element3', 
'Element1', 
'Element1', 
'Element4', 
'Element4', 
'Element2', 
'Element2', 
'Element2', 
'Element2', 
'Element4', 
'Element5', 
'Element5' );

$result = array_count_values($values);
arsort($result);
$result = array_keys($result);
print_r($result);
?>
```